# iBooks Author imports ePub text very large

Tags: books, adobe, epub, ibooks-author

I have an inDesign file that I'm exporting as a fixed ePub. When I import it into iBooks Author using the blank template, the text is gigantic. For instance one text box is set to 389 pt. The text is so large it exceeds the mask around it. The font selection doesn't seem to matter.

Creating outlines solves the issue but I would like to keep it as text. Is there a way to control the size of the text better?

Comment: Yes, I have tried many fonts.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to control text size would be to convert the file to text/markdown. That way you would have total control over the sizing.

It really depends on how proficient you are in editing inDesign or simplifying the formatting there to see if you can tweak things there to isolate the part of the native -> ePub conversion that's running amok.

If you're good there, take a simpler approach to fix things. If you have no aptitude or time to learn inDesign or clean up the document's formatting (I've seen some PageMaker files that got moved to inDesign that are incredibly convoluted and needed to be thrown out and started over from text).

Sorry I can't be more specific. If you want to ask a follow on question with specific details on what item is being converted or can upload a minimal test case, someone might have a better idea on preventing the poor conversion from one format to another.

Comment: I removed the design of the book from the equation by redoing the import from a new file with only 4 text boxes. It had the same issue. I think it is something that needs to be added to the inDesign file as opposed to subtracted from the file.